# Search in formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pretty huge Excel 2016 workbook with tons of sheets. I'm trying to figure out how to search for some formula content but I get lots of false hits from cell values (not formulas).

I've created a minimal example below. This search shouldn't give any result. But it does !

[image]

Any clues?

I only want to search formula content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way (that I know of) to specifically limit searches to formulas, but here's a sort of hacky way to do it.

Since you're looking for content in a formula, you know the formula will start with an equal sign (`=`).  So you can use a find query that starts with `=` and searches for any occurrence of your text after that by using a wildcard, like this:

`=*Howdy`

Using that string in the Find box would return no results in your example above, but would register a hit if you included `Howdy` as part of a formula.